# Expect - How to "send_user" for dynamic variable

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm trying to send dynamic variable in Expect but having problem.

Below is output from router:

```
router# show service id 123 base
sdp 1.1.1.1  Up   Up
sdp 2.2.2.2  Up   Up
...
...
...
sdp 5.5.5.5 Up  Up
...
... 
router#
```

What I'm trying to achieve is

1) extract certain info all line-by-line until finish (x lines)
For example, I want to extract all ip address and set to variable.

sdpip1 = 1.1.1.1

sdpip2 = 1.1.1.2

.......

........

sdpipx = x.x.x.x

```
            while {$count < 10} {
                set linesplit [split $chksdp \n]
                set sdpline [lindex $linesplit 1]
                set sdpfirst [lindex $sdpline 0]


                if {$sdpfirst != $router} {
                    set chksdpA [lindex $sdpline 0]
                    set errsdpline "sdp"

                    if {$chksdpA != $errsdpline} {
                        set sdpval "N/A\n"
                        break
                    } else {

                        set sdpip [lindex $linesplit $indexsdp]
                        set sdpip [lindex $sdpip 1]

                        foreach i $indexsdp {
                            set sdpip$i "$sdpip"
                        }

                        set indexsdp [expr {$indexsdp + 1}]
                        set indexsdpval [expr {$indexsdpval + 1}]
                        set count [expr {$count + 1}]
                        continue
                    }  
            }
```

2) at the end of my script,then I want to send to user all the IP address.. Here I'm having problem..

```
send_user "$sdpip$i\n"
```

I'm unable to send_user using variable that I set before which is

```
                 foreach i $indexsdp {
                     set sdpip$i "$sdpip"
                 }
```

that was mean to set incremental variable for each ip address.

If I manually assign the variable, I'm able to send to user. For example:

```
send_user "$sdpip1\n"
send_user "$sdpip2\n"
send_user "$sdpip3\n"
send_user "$sdpip4\n"
```

So, how can I send to user based on the first script that will extract certain number of lines & ip address? And only send to user that total number of ip address?

Thank you

Comment: Try `send_user "[set sdpip$i]\n"`?

Comment: Thank you @Jerry. I've tried and it works but only if I add it the after  `set sdpip$i "$sdpip"`.in the Foreach loop. If I add anywhere out site the While loop, it doesn't work?

Comment: You'd be advised to use an array (`$sdpip(3)` instead of `$sdpip3`) as that's a lot easier to work with in a loop and yet almost as easy in the rest of your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always harder to work with dynamic variable *names*. Use a list instead:

```
send "show service id 123 base\r"
expect -re {(.*)# ?$} {
    set re_ip {\d+(?:\.\d+){3}}
    set ip_addresses [regexp -all -inline $re_ip $expect_out(1,string)]
}
```

You're using a regex pattern with expect, and capturing parentheses. The `# ?$` bit should match the prompt that is displayed when the command completes. The command output (and also the "show service" command and the first bit of the prompt) will be captured and stored in the `expect_out(1,string)` variable. Then you just need to find the ip addresses in that chunk of text.

When you want to display it to the user:

```
foreach addr $ip_addresses {send_user "$addr\n"}
```